# Fixing "The ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI5 (0,0,0) (sda) failed

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb, ext4

The other day, I was using my gaming laptop (ASUS ROG G750JM) that I got last year when it froze up and shut itself off. When I tried to reboot it has a system 32 error message, since I don't have a windows install disc or key-code, I decided to install Ubuntu from a USB. It was working fine until I got to the step where I had to choose for it to erase the entire disk> I selected yes and when I went to choose my time zone I got the error message.

I had read somewhere that if I chose the option to "do something else" I could mess with the partitions and fix this myself. So I tried right clicking and deleting everything there, like suggested, but I wasn't able to do anything.

If you need further information from me, I will do my best to provide it. Please help me as I would like to avoid turning my one year old laptop into a $1200 paper weight.

Comment: Hi Devlin, unfortunately the links to the images do not work, so I don't know what the error is precisely. But from the title of your question, I take it that there's a HDD/SSD problem. Run a check for bad sectors. Your device is well within warranty. If the drive is toast get Asus to replace it. And have them send a Windows recovery disk with it.

Answer (score 1):

Those beginners that has a same issue with mine, I just want to share this solution that solved to my problem ***"The ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed"***  I know that this is so very annoying because every time the last part of the installation, the worst part is it suddenly failed, I tried many many times installing that OS and spent couple of hours, not just hours but days. I already read lots of threads or Forum and done what they have shared but still it doesn't fix my problem, until such time that I just tried to FORMAT my UBUNTU HARD DISK thru Disks Utility, taraaannnn PROBLEM SOLVED.

Here's what I did;

1. I downloaded the UBUNTU ISO File from Official Site.
2. I made a Bootable USB using my other UBUNTU PC which has a Start Up App that can create start up bootable usb (maybe you can use a Universal USB Installer Bootable if you are using windows or mac).
3. How to make a bootable usd using Start Up? I just Plugged In my USB unto my other Ubuntu PC wherein the ISO File was saved on my USB.
4. Click the Dash and just type Start Up, select the ISO FIle then just Click and browse the ISO File on my USB, click create image disk, after this I already have a Bootable USB Ubuntu OS.

**How to Install?**

5. I plugged In my USB unto my PC that has an issue, restart the pc,
   then when the menu appeared immediately press the DEL on your
   keyboard so that you can go to BIOS Settings, go to BOOT, look for
   UEFI Boot Option Priority then change Boot Option to you USB name, click
   enter and Go to Exit click Save and Reset. Thats it.

   7. On my part after save and reset there is a error code, I just click the TAB  from my keyboard and type LIVE then my pc will automatically reboot.
   8. Now, when you are now on your desktop, click the DASH and type Disk Utility.
   9. Click the Hard Disk, then click the (negative icon beside settings icon so it will stop, click the settings icon and click format, just format that drive until it is freely from space. I mean just format until it no file content.
   10. Now, Go back to your Desktop just double click Install Ubuntu, click Continue, Click Erase and click continue, the next option will show up is the COUNTRY AREA, just click click click continue, then wait for a few minutes for installation.

Once the installation was successful, reboot again your PC and go to BIOS SETTINGS, go to BOOT and change Bootable USB to PC or PC Boot wherein youve change it a while ago. then Go to Exit agin Save and Reset. Thats it.

Sorry for my bad english, I was so very tired while I am typing this message. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try To use RAID controller to erase disk from BIOS without need to external resource,look like it's called Intel Rapid Storage Technology.