# The ext4 file system creation in partition failed to install Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb, usb-drive

I made a bootable pen drive for ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64, now my installation failed every time with the following error

> The ext4/ext3 file system creationin partition#2 of SCSI2(0,0,0)(sda)
>   failed

I tried with ext4 and ext 3 as well.

What I tried,Created following partition

- A boot partition /boot and give it 50GB of space, choose ext4 for the format.
- A root partition / and give it 200GB  of space and ext4 format
- A swap partition /swap and give it 5GB of space (it will format to swap)
- A home partition /home and give it the 500GB of the space and format it to ext4

But its failed every time,tried same with ext3 partition as well but no success.

After this i choose Ubuntu should handle the partition work that also failed with same error .

Even the below link not help me to fix the issue.

[Filesystem creation fails when trying to install Ubuntu over Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356522/filesystem-creation-fails-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu-over-windows)

[The ext4 file system creation in partition of USB drive failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057969/the-ext4-file-system-creation-in-partition-of-usb-drive-failed)

[Fixing "The ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI5 (0,0,0) (sda) failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679880/fixing-the-ext4-file-system-creation-in-partition-1-of-scsi5-0-0-0-sda-fai)

Please have a look in the attached images

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Output of command `dmesg`

> [  115.322333] audit: type=1400 audit(1539844635.741:217):
>   apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current
>   profile, skipping" profile="unconfined"
>   name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=6567 comm="apparmor_parser" [ 
>   115.525149] audit: type=1400 audit(1539844635.945:218): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined"
>   name="snap-update-ns.gnome-system-monitor" pid=6575
>   comm="apparmor_parser" [  115.734850] audit: type=1400
>   audit(1539844636.153:219): apparmor="STATUS"
>   operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined"
>   name="snap.gnome-system-monitor.gnome-system-monitor" pid=6577
>   comm="apparmor_parser" [  115.810202] audit: type=1400
>   audit(1539844636.229:220): apparmor="STATUS"
>   operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping"
>   profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine"
>   pid=6585 comm="apparmor_parser" [  115.810207] audit: type=1400
>   audit(1539844636.229:221): apparmor="STATUS"
>   operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping"
>   profile="unconfined"
>   name="/snap/core/4917/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper"
>   pid=6585 comm="apparmor_parser" [  433.021303]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
>   sda4 < sda5 > [  433.250758] Adding 4881404k swap on /dev/sda1. 
>   Priority:-2 extents:1 across:4881404k FS [  440.560267] ata2.00:
>   exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0 [  440.560273]
>   ata2.00: BMDMA stat 0x25 [  440.560277] ata2.00: failed command: WRITE
>   DMA EXT [  440.560286] ata2.00: cmd
>   35/00:00:00:78:a5/00:04:1d:00:00/e0 tag 0 dma 524288 out
>                           res 61/04:40:d8:68:a5/04:03:1d:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error) [  440.560290] ata2.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR } [ 
>   440.560292] ata2.00: error: { ABRT } [  440.563672] ata2.00: failed to read native max address (err_mask=0x1) [  440.563675] ata2.00: HPA
>   support seems broken, skipping HPA handling [  445.693679] ata2.00: qc
>   timeout (cmd 0xec) [  445.693683] ata2.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O
>   error, err_mask=0x5) [  445.693686] ata2.00: revalidation failed
>   (errno=-5) [  450.734593] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be
>   patient (ready=0) [  455.715286] ata2: device not ready (errno=-16),
>   forcing hardreset [  455.715293] ata2: soft resetting link [ 
>   460.915884] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0) [  465.776389] ata2: SRST failed (errno=-16) [  465.776400] ata2: soft
>   resetting link [  470.976917] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be
>   patient (ready=0) [  475.803416] ata2: SRST failed (errno=-16) [ 
>   475.803424] ata2: soft resetting link [  481.013863] ata2: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0) [  510.853908] ata2: SRST
>   failed (errno=-16) [  510.853920] ata2: soft resetting link [ 
>   515.874825] ata2: SRST failed (errno=-16) [  515.886236] ata2: reset failed, giving up [  515.886240] ata2.00: disabled [  515.886263]
>   ata2: EH complete [  515.886310] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED
>   Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.886316] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1d a5 78 00 00 04 00 00 [ 
>   515.886318] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 497383424 [  515.886333] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 60952320, lost async page write [  515.886343] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical
>   block 60952321, lost async page write [  515.886345] Buffer I/O error
>   on dev sda2, logical block 60952322, lost async page write [ 
>   515.886348] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 60952323, lost async page write [  515.886352] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical
>   block 60952324, lost async page write [  515.886354] Buffer I/O error
>   on dev sda2, logical block 60952325, lost async page write [ 
>   515.886356] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 60952326, lost async page write [  515.886359] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical
>   block 60952327, lost async page write [  515.886363] Buffer I/O error
>   on dev sda2, logical block 60952328, lost async page write [ 
>   515.886365] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 60952329, lost async page write [  515.886476] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result:
>   hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.886479] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1d a5 7c 00 00 04 00 00 [ 
>   515.886480] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 497384448 [  515.886571] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.886573] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1d a5 80 00 00 04 00 00 [ 
>   515.886574] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 497385472 [  515.886664] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.886666] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1d a5 84 00 00 04 00 00 [ 
>   515.886667] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 497386496 [  515.886764] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.886767] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1d a5 88 00 00 04 00 00 [ 
>   515.886768] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 497387520 [  515.886865] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.886868] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1d a5 8c 00 00 04 00 00 [ 
>   515.886869] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 497388544 [  515.886963] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.886965] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1d a5 90 00 00 04 00 00 [ 
>   515.886966] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 497389568 [  515.887062] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.887064] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1d a5 94 00 00 04 00 00 [ 
>   515.887065] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 497390592 [  515.887161] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.887164] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1d a5 98 00 00 04 00 00 [ 
>   515.887165] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 497391616 [  515.887252] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.887254] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 1d a5 9c 00 00 04 00 00 [ 
>   515.887255] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 497392640 [  515.895151] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.895154] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available. [  515.895343] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]
>   Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET
>   driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.895344] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not
>   available. [  515.895479] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks:
>   (0 B/0 B) [  515.895481] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks [
>   515.895575] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is on [  515.895576] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: ab 2a 28 ff [  515.895930] sda: detected
>   capacity change from 1000204886016 to 0 [  515.901323] sd 1:0:0:0:
>   [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET
>   driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.901327] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not
>   available. [  515.901348] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed:
>   Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  515.901350] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available. [  515.901660] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]
>   Write Protect is off [  515.901662] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00
>   00 00 00 [  618.129090] scsi_io_completion: 116 callbacks suppressed [
>   618.129096] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [  618.129101] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00
>   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00 [ 1217.889362] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda]
>   tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [
>   1217.889368] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: ATA command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5 00 [ 1818.068632] sd
>   1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET
>   driverbyte=DRIVER_OK [ 1818.068637] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: ATA
>   command pass through(16) 85 06 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e5
>   00 [ 1912.546340] R8188EU: sta recv deauth reason code(2)
>   sta:c4:e9:84:24:7e:0c [ 1912.552931] R8188EU: indicate disassoc [
>   1915.619213] R8188EU: indicate disassoc [ 1918.691319] R8188EU: indicate disassoc [ 1921.763424] R8188EU: indicate disassoc [
>   1928.070991] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx0013ef8d2c6b: link is not ready [ 1932.003793] R8188EU: indicate disassoc [ 1943.732689]
>   R8188EU: assoc success [ 1943.742538] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE):
>   wlx0013ef8d2c6b: link becomes ready

**EDIT 2**

[image]

**EDIT 3**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl -A /dev/sda
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-29-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   253   178   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       2083
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       956
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       1960
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       952
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       337
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   188   188   000    Old_age   Always       -       37488
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   113   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
```

Comment: @george added the images as well.

Comment: Can you make sure (with `sudo parted -l`) your partition type is gpt and not msdos ? look for:
Partition Table: gpt
installer can have issues on non gpt partition. this can be fixed with program called gparted.

Comment: The disk is possibly defective. Did you try to get its SMART data?

Comment: There is a "Read Capacity(19) failed:..." error in the log. Can you open a console and post the output of `dmesg`?

Comment: @SimonSudler edited question with the output

Comment: @janmyszkier run the command and its showing for Pen Drive and not for Hard Disk.

Comment: If I remember correctly, I read somewhere that this was a known bug (I can't find it now, though). Try using gparted to edit partition from Ubuntu live and then install it.

Comment: @subodh please run gparted from the live image, and check there with View -> Device Information

Comment: @francescop21 Any idea how to use gparted from installation pen drive ?

Comment: @subodh just press menu and type "gparted" in ;) or install with `apt-get install gparted`

Comment: @janmyszkier i am in test mode of Ubuntu there Gparted showing only the Pen Drive Information

Comment: To mee this sound more like a failing harddrive... check the `smartctl -A /dev/sda` (https://serverfault.com/questions/520930/is-this-a-sign-of-dying-hard-drive). Install it with `sudo apt install smartmontools`

Comment: @janmyszkier Added another images for gparted output

Comment: @subodh what about device information? can you post it? if you don't care about drive contents please do: Device -> Create partition table, and from the dropdown, select "GPT". this should format the disk correctly and allow you to install ubuntu on it.

Comment: @janmyszkier i added the output as well,do you mean installation time ? I select First option at the time of installation but that ended with same issue

Comment: posted as an answer

Answer (score 6):

had to post as an answer becasue comments doesn't allow you to input images:
If you open gparted, you have a menu in it.
When you open `View -> Device Information` you should see something like:
[image: Device information]

If you partition table is NOT gpt, please use (from menu) `Device -> Create Partition Table` :
[image: Create Partition Table]

and make sure to select gpt from the dropdown.

One your disk is having gpt partition table, you should be able to install ubuntu without issues.

EDIT:
However! if you look at the EDIT3 of your post (whih I didn't read before), it looks like your disk is failing. See values for `Raw_Read_Error_Rate` and `Seek_Error_Rate` They are VERY high. Also some messages in `dmesg` indicate your drive is failing and needs replacement.

Comment: I dont have GPT option in my partition table

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted you should change it TO gpt. It's probably msdos now. It should be gpt.

Comment: Ok I got it i have to delete all partition and then only got it.

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to format Input/output error during write on /dev/sda

Comment: updated answer, your disk is broken and needs replacement

Comment: Do you mean hard disk not usable now? I have to replace it ? No other solution is possible .

Comment: Exactly, this drive is failing bad. that's what SMART stats show you.

Comment: Its a hardware issue ? Or can be fix at home?

Comment: this is a hardware issue. cannot be fixed with software.

Comment: Ok But why its showing harddrive properly even formatting also working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84624/discussion-between-janmyszkier-and-subodh).

Comment: KDE Partition will do the same for you if installing Lubuntu.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. It saved my old laptop and made is usable again.