# The ext4 file system creation in partition #4 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) failed

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu for the past few days.
But every time I hit install, I get this error `The ext4 file system creation in partition #4 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) failed` My partitioning table for my 1 tb HDD is: 250mb as EFI, 8gb as swap, 400gb ext4 mounted on root
, and 600gb ext4 mounted on /home.
I'm installing Ubuntu as the only OS on an ASUS laptop.
Important note: I did a variety of checks for the health of my HDD, and I found some issues.
But I was able to install windows 10 with no issues.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The ext4 file system creation in partition failed to install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084781/the-ext4-file-system-creation-in-partition-failed-to-install-ubuntu)

Comment: One hack to let you know your laptop is fine and Ubuntu works is to make one partition for root and home together.  Just mounted as /  Then put that partition at the end or the beginning hoping to avoid the bad parts of your HDD.  Once a hard drive starts to go however it will die completely.  Replace it.

Comment: Have you tried partitioning in advance. Be sure to choose gpt, first from drop down menu in gparted. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &