# ext4 file system creation fails while installing Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, ext4, usb-installation

I installed Ubuntu a few days ago (I'm a beginner), and when I started installing it, I got a message saying that

`The ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) (sda) failed`.

I searched for many solutions, (including manually creating the partitions for the installation), but non of them worked, I always get the same mistake. I tried re-installing the Ubuntu image to the USB, but I get the same mistake.

Now i have a completely allocated disk, so I am open to any solution you guys can give me. Thanks so much in advance.

(Sorry if my description is clumsy, I don't natively speak English).

Comment: Can see this link.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084781/the-ext4-file-system-creation-in-partition-failed-to-install-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks so much, guess I'll have to change my HDD.

Comment: Read whole link first, some answers are not about bad HD, unless you are getting a lot of HD errors.

Comment: Thanks to you all, just wanted to update, I changed the HDD and everything went fine